# How to parse HTML by using libxml2? I need to real code examples

Tags: html, c, libxml2

I'm looking for an code example how to parse HTML by using libxml2. The official web page just contains prototype declarations and some description. I need to real code examples. `XPath` and `DOM` of HTMLParser module. I did a lot of googling; but I don't get any satisfactory result. I found only tutorials about xml parsing and much obj-c examples(I want to pure C).

Comment: HTML doesn't have to be well-formed. It is hardly practical to parse HTML with XML parser.

Comment: Despite its name, it can parse HTML as well.

Comment: Looking for code examples? Perhaps you have tried internet?

Comment: @Jack. It seems it can. I didn't know.

Comment: @tbert: Yes. I am. As I have mentioned: "the official web page just contains prototype declarations and some description [...] I did a lot of googling; but I don't get any satisfactory result. I found only tutorials about xml parsing and much obj-c examples(I want to pure C)."

Comment: @bioffe, libxml has both an XML and an HTML parser.

Comment: @bioffe, HTML does have to be well formed, but it often isn't since browsers fix a lot of errors. That said, you can recover from those errors. (In the Perl interface to libxml2, it's done by setting the `recover` option.)